# problem occures in if condition

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I am tring to give condition, but it cant give appropriate result.

like

```
if($this->data['EmployeeExprienceDetail']['file_name']['type'] != 'image/jpeg')
```

is this condition is ok or not...guide me

thanks

Comment: (-1) Impossible to answer. What condition are you trying to match? Where is the data array coming from? What value does the variable have at the moment? The first thing to do here is a test output `echo $this->data['EmployeeExprienceDetail']['file_name']['type']`

Comment: Please expand your code example. Also you need to be aware that some browsers report media types differently, so consider using more conditions or a regex.

Comment: @DavidYell given the tags and the dollar-sign before the variable name, I think it's safe to assume a browser isn't going to be affecting anything. It looks like he's using PHP.

Comment: Well yes of course, but the type field in the uploaded file array will be reported by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to check what is being passed back it to output what you want to validate against.

This will print the value to the screen

```
echo $this->data['EmployeeExprienceDetail']['file_name']['type']."<br />";
```

This will print the (if array) value to the screen

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($this->data['EmployeeExprienceDetail']['file_name']['type'],true)."</pre><br />";
```

This will print the raw value(s) to the screen

```
echo var_dump($this->data['EmployeeExprienceDetail']['file_name']['type']);
```

This will print the value to the screen, useful for displaying whitespace as you might need to trim the value before comparing it

```
echo "|".$this->data['EmployeeExprienceDetail']['file_name']['type']."|<br />";
```